# Remove iframe on scroll to a specific point

Tags: javascript, css, html, youtube-iframe-api

I need to remove an youtube iframe on scroll to a specific point of website. This is what i am done so far. By using this script  I an hide the section containing youtube iframe but still video is playing    [My website link](http://cableandmedia.com/abra2017/)

```css
.rem{
display:none;
}
```

```js
    
        <script>
   $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var section1Height = $('#types-of-repair').offset().top + $('#types-of-repair').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight;
   if (scroll >= 3) {
       
        $(".about-section").addClass("rem"); 
       $(".clearHeader111").addClass("rem"); 
       
    }
 
     
   
});
    </script>
```

```html
    <section class="about-section">
     <div class="pattern"></div>
               <div class="clearHeader1 video-background">
    <div class="clearHeader11 video-foreground">
    
      <iframe class="clearHeader111" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DEDS-bSHRfI?controls=1&showinfo=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&&amp;ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly what you are looking for but;

I would add a pause trigger to it to stop playing the music.

I can't use your snippets to test it but adding something like this should work.

`document.getElementByClassName('clearHeader111').iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');`

You can also reverse its effect by replacing `pauseVideo` with `playVideo`